# Can the compiler elide copies of specific data members?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Take this code:

```
struct Bar { //has non-default copy-constructor
    Bar() = default;
    Bar(const Bar&) {} 
};
struct LargeObject { //has default copy-constructor
    std::array<char, 1000> m_chars;
};
struct Foo {
    Bar m_bar;
    LargeObject m_obj;
};
Foo func() { Foo f; return f; }
```

The compiler can't elide a copy when the copy-constructor is specified by the user. What about when a member of a class has a non-default copy constructor? In this code, when `f` is returned from `func`, can the compiler elide the copy of `m_obj` or will everything have to be copied?

Comment: if `Foo` is copied all of its members will be copied.

Comment: Copying leaves the source intact, moving not, hence it would be wrong to move one member when a `Foo` is copied

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai What if you are returning a local Foo from a function? Wouldn't it not matter in that case?

Comment: I am only refering to what you wrote. When you move a `Foo` then the members can be moved, but when you copy a `Foo` then you need to copy them.

Comment: And when a copy is elided, nothing gets copied, or moved.

Comment: copy elision is what happens in certain situations, but you do not show any code where a copy could be elided. Could it be that you are asking what the compiler generated copy and move of `Foo` will do? As currently stated it is difficult to understand what you are asking - edit: ok, slightly better now

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: `Foo f;` is a compiler error

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai just fixed it.

Comment: @TwistedBlizzard: Why do you think the copy constructor prevents copy elision? The whole point of the language allowing copy elision/RVO/NRVO is to make an exception to the usual as-if rule, and allow the compiler to perform the optimization even though it might change observed behavior by not execute any code in the custom copy/move constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is based on a faulty premise. The compiler is perfectly within its rights to elide a copy like this, whether or not the class itself, or one of its members, has a non-default copy (or move) constructor. The benefit of [the copy-elision rules introduced since C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) is to allow this sort of optimization even when it violates the as-if rule.

If it couldn't do that, copy elision wouldn't be all that useful; a class with even a single smart pointer (which has custom copy and move constructors) would be ineligible for RVO unless the compiler could prove, with certainty, that the as-if rule was not being violated.

In your specific scenario, the compiler can, and with optimizations enabled, usually will (it's not mandatory since you're relying on non-mandatory NRVO, not the C++17 guaranteed copy elision for simple RVO) implement `func` by directly constructing the `Foo` object into the caller-provided storage, without using a separate `Foo f` that would have to be moved/copied back to the caller.